# my responsive menu is not working in mobile version

Tags: javascript, responsive

My menu is not working in mobile version. can you please have a look at it. I think there is just the problem of javascript or somethingn is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have js error in your file /android/js/custom.js :

```
custom.js:241 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function(anonymous function) @ custom.js:241(anonymous function) @ custom.js:386
```

So, just replace all .live() methods to .on() in this custom.js file. Use replace all in text editor or in your IDE.